# What does this error mean? Exception: (13) setup_call_catcher_cleanup

Tags: loops, prolog, runtime-error, prolog-findall

What does this error mean? And how do I solve it? (In theory of course.)
The program is to complex to put here.

```
ERROR: Out of global stack
^  Exception: (13) setup_call_catcher_cleanup('$bags':'$new_findall_bag', '$bags':findall_loop(_G15784496, user:member([_G15784496|_G15784497], [[ (-8, 3, ..., ...), (-8, ..., ...)], [ (-8, ..., ...), (..., ...)], [ (..., ...)|...], [...|...]|...]), _G15784504, []),
```

the trace on my program returns me this:

```
  (22) veiculos_troncos(_G6698) ? creep
   Exit: (22) veiculos_troncos((4, 6)) ? creep
   Redo: (22) veiculos_troncos(_G6698) ? creep
   Exit: (22) veiculos_troncos((-3, 4)) ? creep
   Redo: (22) veiculos_troncos(_G6698) ? creep
   Exit: (22) veiculos_troncos((-9, 4)) ? creep
   Redo: (22) veiculos_troncos(_G6698) ? creep
   Exit: (22) veiculos_troncos((-8, 4)) ? creep
   Redo: (22) veiculos_troncos(_G6698) ? creep
   Exit: (22) veiculos_troncos((3, 6)) ? creep
   Redo: (22) veiculos_troncos(_G6698) ? creep
   Exit: (22) veiculos_troncos((-5, 6)) ? creep
   Redo: (22) veiculos_troncos(_G6698) ? creep
   Exit: (22) veiculos_troncos((-7, 4)) ? creep
   Redo: (22) veiculos_troncos(_G6698) ? creep
   Exit: (22) veiculos_troncos((-2, 4)) ? creep
   Redo: (22) veiculos_troncos(_G6698) ? creep
   Exit: (22) veiculos_troncos((3, 4)) ? creep
   Redo: (22) veiculos_troncos(_G6698) ? creep
   Exit: (22) veiculos_troncos((0, 4)) ? creep
   Redo: (22) veiculos_troncos(_G6698) ? creep
    Exit: (22) veiculos_troncos((-6, 4)) ? creep
   Redo: (22) veiculos_troncos(_G6698) ? creep
   Exit: (22) veiculos_troncos((1, 4)) ? creep
   Redo: (22) veiculos_troncos(_G6698) ? creep
   Exit: (22) veiculos_troncos((-4, 6)) ? creep
   Redo: (22) veiculos_troncos(_G6698) ? creep
   Exit: (22) veiculos_troncos((-7, 6)) ? creep
   Exit: (22) veiculos_troncos((8, 7)) ? creep
   Redo: (22) veiculos_troncos(_G6698) ? creep
   Exit: (22) veiculos_troncos((1, 5)) ? creep
   Redo: (22) veiculos_troncos(_G6698) ? creep
   Exit: (22) veiculos_troncos((2, 7)) ? creep
   Redo: (22) veiculos_troncos(_G6698) ? creep
   Exit: (22) veiculos_troncos((0, 5)) ? creep
```

And it keeps going round and round through the same points again and again

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762591/out-of-global-stack-error-in-prolog

Comment: the out of stack part I understand . The rest I don't. I have a findall that is looping .